# How do I return a Typing activity from my v4 Bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to add a Typing activity to a long-running action in my bot, but I keep getting a "BadGateway" error. Most of the samples I've found seem to be for bot framework v3, so the types or methods don't appear any more, and I've tried a few options for v4 (using C#), like the following:

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(new Activity() { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing });
```

or

```
var typingActivity = new Activity()
{
    Type = ActivityTypes.Typing
    //RelatesTo = turnContext.Activity
};

typingActivity.ApplyConversationReference(typingActivity.GetConversationReference());
```

or

```
var act2 = MessageFactory.Text(null);
act2.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(act2);
```

all of these result in a BadGateway error.

Can someone guide me on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is related, because I'm testing in web as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768474/i-get-an-error-onturnerrorunknown-error-on-sendactivity-of-bot . @StevenKanberg, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Steven Kanberg has the right code, but unfortunately this is a service issue at the moment, as confirmed in this [issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/194).

When the issue is resolved, it should be posted in the Github issue above.

Comment: Thanks Mick, that explains it

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is close, but needs a couple minor adjustments. Also, the text property is optional. If it's not needed, then you can simply remove it (same for the delay). This is what I use which adheres to the documentation (variable is used to match your code). You can reference the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#send-a-typing-indicator).

```
var typingActivity = new Activity[] {
    new Activity { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing },
    new Activity { Type = "delay", Value= 3000 },
    //MessageFactory.Text("Some message", "Some message"),
};

await turnContext.SendActivitiesAsync(typingActivity, cancellationToken);
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Hi Steven. I did see this example yesterday, but haven't tested it yet. I don't understand how it's different from example 1 that I posted above (await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(new Activity() { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing });), other than that it sends multiple activies. Is the "delay" required to make "typing" work?

Comment: Still the same result my side unfortunately. Of course I've tested that the basics are working, so I can do something like: 
   var response = MessageFactory.Text(text);
   await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
it's just the typing indicator that's giving trouble. Does it matter that this turn was invoked from an adaptive card action?

Comment: What is it doing, just skipping over the typing indicator? I haven't had luck with sending a delay activity but I think it depends on the channel.

Comment: Hi All, I am facing the same issue. I tried this but still getting the same exception, "Bad gateway". It was working fine earlier but now it is going for the exception. Is there anything I can do to show the typing indicator now?

Answer (score 0):

Please try out this code to send a typing activity from your bot:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   var typingActivity = MessageFactory.Text(string.Empty);
   typingActivity.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
   await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(typingActivity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gousia for the reply. That's basically the same as my 3rd example, except with string.Empty instead of null - I didn't mention in my original post, but I tried that too, and it also didn't work. I tried again now to confirm, same result (BadGateway).