# I get an error [OnTurnError]:Unknown Error on SendActivity of bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

My bot integrated into microsoft teams ,gives out an error after SentActivity call in webapp based teams
but works fine on Desktop Application of Teams.

Code failing -

```
await stepContext.context.sendActivity({
            type: 'typing'
        });
```

The above logic only fails for web based teams and not on Desktop application.
Any idea ,why that is?

Also the code below works perfectly fine in both-

```
await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Hello There");
```

Comment: I'm seeing something similar (typing activities in Web-based Teams failing - I haven't tested in desktop) - see my open question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710065/how-do-i-return-a-typing-activity-from-my-v4-bot

Comment: i see, what kind of error due you get in the log. Bad gateway? Also you could try out the same with desktop application and confirm,if it works,it would atleast get us closer to the root cause.

Comment: yes, badgateway. I can't check now but I'll try a bit later. What do you get on mobile?

Comment: I tried mobile,Android App and it works fine there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your Teams tenant within the Western European region? Unfortunately this is a service error at the moment, as confirmed in this [issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/194).

When the issue is resolved, it should be posted in the Github issue above.

Comment: Hi glad to know,also had one more question ,im not able to access web-bot server hosted on azure using git. It is throwing error "fatal: unable to access 'va-chatbot-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/va-chatbot.git': The requested URL returned error: 403". Is this issue related too?

Comment: @sree, no this is not related to the Teams API outage. Your problem looks related to your App Service and/or configuration, thus I would create a ticket in the Azure portal.

Comment: @sree have a look at the [official statement](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/blogs/outage-bots-posting-typing-indicators-will-receive-502s/) regarding the API outage.

Comment: Hi Mick yes..thats some other issue.Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Mick. @Sree - This is related to the recent outage happened in Europe region. My team has already raised the ticket for this.

Comment: Hi  glad to know,also had one more question ,im  not able to access web-bot server hosted on azure using git. It is throwing error "fatal: unable to access 'https://va-chatbot-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/va-chatbot.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403". Is this issue related too?